# How to find corrct page in paging base on post id in PHP and MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, facebook, video

I have a website, http://www.yatha.tv

On top of the list(grid style) there is YouTube video post.

My list have paging. So every video post url have video id (vid) and page id (id).

http://www.yatha.tv/play.php?vid=97&id=1

application itself is working find. I am sharing those video url to Facebook.

Few day later, there are new post added and older post paging change. When user click the link that video is showing correct but list of page is wrong.

For example, above video is at page 2 but list is showing first page.

So I am thinking not to add page id in url and only show the page base on post id.

So my question is how to show a correct page base on post id in PHP MySQL.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: What pages are you talking about? Also, that bearded girl scarred me.

Comment: Hi Shahar, what I mean is that paging id. you look up the url. there is video id and paging id. Facebook is remembering that address. If I add new post, old post paging is changed. So, if user click the link from Facebook, it is always show first page.

Answer (score 0):

Of course - as you add more videos, it will be on different pages. I'd advise you to remove the page ID from the URL. You can just calculate what page it is in using PHP code when you load the page, and then Javascript to toggle between pages. You should make the pagination system client-sided; it doesn't really make sense to reload the page every time someone wants to go to the previous/next page.